# How to do animation frame by frame?

Tags: beamer, animations

I have three frames in beamer containing images that I want to show as an animation in one frame (there must be the animation tool box below, just like the attached picture for example). Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=6cm]{1.png}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=6cm]{2.png}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=6cm]{3.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have never used animation before in beamer. Any help or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Try `\item<1>` or `\includegraphics<2>`, the `<n>` annotation is exactly for "show only in the n-th part of the animation".

Answer (score 2):

If you must have an "animation tool box", the animate package is your friend:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\animategraphics[controls,step]{12}{}{1}{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*(Many thanks to @AlexG for the useful hint about the `step` option!)*

Comment: For stepping, adding option `step` may be useful. A reduced set of controls is shown, and clicking directly on the "animation" advances by one frame at  time and loops back to the first at the end of the sequence.

Comment: Well, insider knowledge ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Empty file sequence basename (`{}`) in `\animategraphics`, because the files in OP indeed don't have one. Only `<number>.png`.